# Event.keyCode works once but not after on other objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm currently attempting to make a sort of a chatting system, where first you can set your username and then send messages and both of the buttons, to set username and to send messages would trigger off of pressing enter, but for some reason it will not take the input for the messages, first it shows the username setting field

```
  <input id = "name" type = "text" name = "name" value = "" maxlength="20" placeholder = "Aseta käyttäjänimesi tähän">
      <button id="user" type= "button" name="button" onclick = "setUsername()">
```

and this sets so enter makes it set it

```
   var input = document.getElementById("name");
   var x = 0;
   input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("user").click();
```

after the username is set, the fields are replaced by these by using socket.io to check if the user is set:

```
  socket.on('userSet', function(data) {
     user = data.username;
     document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="messagebox"><input type = "text" id = "message" placeholder = "Kirjoita viestisi tähän">\
     <button type = "button" id="sending" name = "button" onclick = "sendMessage()">Send</button></div>\
     <div id = "message-container"></div></div>';

  });
```

after creating the new inputs, I have a piece of code that should make enter run the function to send messages which is:

```
  function sendMessage() {
     var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
     if(msg) {
        socket.emit('msg', {message: msg, user: user});
        $('#message').val('');
     }
  }
```

and this should make so that enter sends the messages, but it does not work at all:

```
var inputtwo = document.getElementById("message");
inputtwo.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("sending").click();
    alert("Toimii");
    }
 });
```

for no apparent reason the latter input listener doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Teemu so I need to prevent default action and use key instead of keyCode, I will give it a try

Comment: Umh ... you can't prevent the default action of `keyup` since that doesn't exist, you need to listen to `keydown` ... or the submit event itself.

Comment: I see I will fix that too

Comment: For now I haven't gotten it to work, any ideas on what to use instead of event.key or such actions? @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing:

```
var inputtwo = document.getElementById("message");
inputtwo.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("sending").click();
    alert("Toimii");
    }
 });
```

into:

```
  var inputtwo = document.getElementById("message");
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.defaultPrevented) {
        return;
      }
      var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
      if( key === 'Enter' || key === 13) {
        sendMessage();
        }
     });
```